# GCC flag that reduce constant (.word) at end of function section

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, arm, compiler-optimization

I am developing a C code for cortex-m0p, using arm-none-eabi-gcc. Because of code size limitation I am using -Os as my optimization flag.

I have been struggling with an issue that is solved by the -O2 flag, however this comes with a big code size increase. I would like to know which specific gcc flag is triggering the behavior I want, so I can add it together with the -Os flag.

Here is my example code that can be checked on https://godbolt.org/ using compiler ARM GCC 11.2.1 (none):

```
typedef union {
    unsigned int   reg32[1];
    unsigned short reg16[2];
    unsigned char  reg8[4];
} halprop_reg32;

typedef struct MY_REGMAP_S
{
    volatile halprop_reg32 cfg;
    unsigned char reserved_0[36];
    volatile halprop_reg32 stat;
} MY_REGMAP_T;

volatile unsigned int offset;

void func()
{
    unsigned int ptr = 1073750016 + offset;

    ((MY_REGMAP_T *) (ptr))->cfg.reg32[0] = 0;
    ((MY_REGMAP_T *) (ptr))->stat.reg8[0] = 0;
}
```

Checking the disassembly generated when using the -Os flag (full compiler options: `-Os -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb`), I have:

```
func():
        ldr     r3, .L2
        ldr     r2, .L2+4
        ldr     r3, [r3]
        adds    r1, r3, r2
        movs    r2, #0
        str     r2, [r1]
        ldr     r1, .L2+8
        adds    r3, r3, r1
        strb    r2, [r3]
        bx      lr
.L2:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
        .word   1073750016
        .word   1073750056
offset:
```

Checking the disassembly generated when using the -O2 flag (full compiler options: `-O2 -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb`), I have:

```
func():
        ldr     r2, .L3
        movs    r1, #40
        mov     ip, r2
        movs    r2, #0
        ldr     r3, .L3+4
        ldr     r3, [r3]
        add     r3, r3, ip
        str     r2, [r3]
        strb    r2, [r3, r1]
        bx      lr
.L3:
        .word   1073750016
        .word   .LANCHOR0
offset:
```

We can see that, on both cases, 2 constants (.word) are added at the end of the function section, one is the address of my global variable (.LANCHOR0), and the other is the base address of what I am trying to access (1073750016), however, when compiling with -Os, another constant is also added, (1073750056) where it already holds the base address and the struct-offset for the register `stat` I am trying to access.

With the -O2 flag, gcc is smart to use `strb    r2, [r3, r1]` this trigger the store with the base address and another register that had the register `stat` offset previously loaded `movs r1, #40`
While the -Os flag is loading again a constant with the register `stat` offset (`ldr     r1, .L2+8`), and re-adding it to the offset variable (`adds    r3, r3, r1`) so it can do a store `strb    r2, [r3]`.

The flag change from -Os to -O2 does not increase any instruction, but reduced a constant (.word) that is twice the size of a instruction. This makes -O2 to end up with a smaller code (on this example).

I would like to know exactly which gcc flag triggers this behavior, so I can incorporate it with the -Os, without bringing all the other flags -O2 has.

For the record, I also tried with GCC none 4.9 and 10.3, also with -flto flag, but this code always get smaller with the -O2 flag...

I already tried everything around here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

And also the flags that appears in the `gcc --help=optimization` command.
No luck into getting what I want, except when I enable -O2 flag.

Comment: After reading your explanation multiple times it is not clear to me what problem you want to solve. Is it that you want to get the smallest possible code and sometimes `-O2` results in smaller code size than `-Os`? You wrote "I have been struggling with *an issue* that is solved by the -O2 flag". What is the issue? Different resulting code? I might have counted wrong, but I think the total nunber of bytes is the same in both examples. Please [edit] your question and add clarification.

Comment: Hello Bodo, the only reason the total amount of bytes is the same, is because there is a padding with a `nop` added on the -O2 optimization, which means effectively there are 2 less bytes in that function.

Comment: This is a small example of my issue, when we go into big functions with hundreds of accesses into registers, code could be smaller and even faster. I don't understand why GCC is re-loading a constant when it was already on a register it could have just summed with an immediate for an offset. Effectively I would like to know what cause this difference, the -Os/O2 should be just a group of other flags.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information or clarification. I suggest to modify the code to allow compiling it without any dependencies, e.g. on https://godbolt.org/ and provide all compiler options you use (apart from `-O2` or `-Os`), so we can experiment with compiler options.

Comment: Thanks Bodo, godbolt website is powerful! I will definitively use it more often for checking flags!

Comment: Question has been edited with a fully compile-able code. And the disassembly adjusted to the godbolt output. I also tested some different gcc versions to be sure, got the same result.

Comment: The GCC documentation about `-Os` lists a few explicitly named optimization options which don't seem to have the desired effect, and it also explains: "It [...] causes the compiler to tune for code size rather than execution speed, and performs further optimizations designed to reduce code size." The code difference might be caused by this unspecified tuning or optimization. Maybe you could ask on a suitable GCC mailing list, see https://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html